# How to specify data in models.ManyToManyField(Foo,Bar)

Tags: python, database, django

I'm working on an application were I want the user roles to be entered into a table in the database.

```
class Role(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
 details = models.TextField()

class Foo(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
 details = models.TextField()

class Bar(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
 detauls = models.TextField()
 foos = models.ManyToMany(Foo,related_name="foo_binding_and_roles")
```

I want the schema of the table foo_binding_and_roles to resemble:

```
{|id|Foo_id|Bar_id|Role_id|}
```

I'm still scratching my head on this, wondering if it's even possible. I know if I write a custom manager I could pull it off but I want to avoid that.

The idea behind this scheme, is to assign users permissions on a relational basis when bar meets foo and foo meets bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what exactly you are trying to do, but reading this line: `{|id|Foo_id|Bar_id|Role_id|}`

makes me think you could either define a model with those fields, or set up a [through model](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) with that extra field.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify this so you can think of it more clearly, don't use many-to-many associations, and build your entire scheme using many-to-one associations. If I understood you right, I think what you're looking for is possible using a three-way association class.